# Placing a JavaScript event on a dynamically loaded PHP form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

**Solution:**

Thanks to Shmiddty, I figured this out:

```
$( static parent element ).on('submit', '#add_client', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    firm.addUser( $(this), '/ci/firm/add_client', 'client' );
});
```

**Description:**

I building some forms for a client. I want this form to be dynamically created depending on the link he clicks. This form is going to be auto-populated with some data.

Here is the `jQuery` that will create the dynamic content:

```
$('.create').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    utility.create_modal(); // dynamic div with form
});
```

This is the function that creates the div and place the `PHP` form in the `html`:

```
$(document.createElement('div')).attr({
    'class' : 'span3'
}).html( create_div( '/ci/firm/return_user_form/client', 'html' ) ),
```

Here is the `ajax` function:

```
var result = '';
$.ajax({
    url: path, 
    type: 'get', 
     dataType: type,
     async : false,
     success: function(data) {
         result = data;
     } 
    });
return result;
```

This is the html that is pulled from the `PHP` file: (it's a huge form, i'm just going to include the button in question)

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Client"  id="add_client">
```

**Problem:**

This dynamic `html` content has a form in it. I want to place a `JavaScript` event ON the form that I included. Is this possible? If so, how can I do it?

This does not work (`#add_client` is the id of the button in the form):

```
$('#add_client').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Please show the actual HTML generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('some_parent_selector').on('click', '#add_client', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The `on` listener needs a parent object (that is not dynamic) to listen for a click event that bubbles up. Then, when the event bubbles up to the parent, it determines whether or not it originated from `'#add_client'`, and if it does, it calls your anonymous function.

Comment: I hate spending 10 minutes to write a question and have it answered in 2.... haha, thank you very much kind sir!